# How to parse string into specific format of date time in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, string, parsing, datetime

I have a string in c# which contains date time value.Now as per my requirement i have to parse this string into Datetime as my mysql database table contains column name like this ..

```
`call_time` datetime NOT NULL,
```

Here is my string datetime Value

```
String datetime="11/02 05:01";
```

Now as per my requirement i have to parse this string into datetime datatype of mysql field.

Please help me.

Comment: @GrantWinney its Feb 11 and time is hh:mm

Comment: @Pranav what about if it is 05:11pm?

Comment: @Pranav what would be the output if time is 11/02/2014 05:01 PM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse a string representation of a date into an actual `DateTime` like this:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(datetime, "dd/MM HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

It assumes the year is the current year since that's not provided, and treats the hour as 24-hour since you don't have AM/PM. You'll get something like this:

`2/11/2014 5:01:00 AM`

Comment: what would be the output of this string on parsing 11/02 05:01

Answer (score 0):

in c#

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(datetime, "dd/MM HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: Formate is dd/mm hh:mm

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String datetime="11/02 05:01";
DateTime dt =  DateTime.ParseExact(datetime, "dd/MM HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

`DateTime.ParseExact` converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its DateTime equivalent using the specified format and culture-specific format information. The format of the string representation must match the specified format exactly.

Syntax:

```
public static DateTime ParseExact(
    string s,
    string format,
    IFormatProvider provider
)
```

Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Without defining date format it is too dificult to convert string into datetime. following example will take current year in result

```
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
string dtFormat = "dd/MM HH:mm";
String datetime="11/02 05:01";
DateTime dtDate = DateTime.ParseExact(datetime, dtFormat, culture);
```

Answer (score 0):

try following code:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(your_date, "dd/MM HH:mm" , CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

this will convert your string into datetime format as per your requirement.

Comment: Hi shruti you should read comments in the question. the date format is dd/MM hh:mm.